# How to Display 2 tables of 2 content types on one page in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, view, cart, commerce

Can anyone help me?
I'm in need of displaying 2 tables on one page.
Those 2 tables are actually shopping cart info, but holds different content type.
[This](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1484581/6314775/5695be5a-b9ec-11e4-9ffb-0825d18d743c.png) is the link of an image how the page should be seen.

Answer (score 1):

You could make two views and include them in a page. 
You will need to use views_embed_view (https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7)

Are you using D6 or D7?

Comment: views_embed_view, as Nick suggested or create block views (display type = block) and the place 2 of them in same content region.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to apply Views Group By field in your view?
Have a look at [Drupal 7 Views - list group by field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828952/drupal-7-views-list-group-by-field) answer.

Comment: But the problem is that... two tables are not the same... as you can see the picture i gave a link.

Comment: Than, just create 2 separate views, and add one as a attachment to another one.

Comment: can you please explain it in detail? i've tried it several times, but failed.