# Make Drupal 7 Group by always show grouping field

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view

I have a Drupal 7 view similar to the one described here: [Drupal 7 Views - list group by field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828952/drupal-7-views-list-group-by-field)

I wish to have all the groupby fields always appear even if there are not members of them and ideally I wish to put a default value in such a list.

eg:

```
Foo:
    -Jay
    -George
Bar:
    -Barry
Boo:
    Sorry no entries at this time!
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If none of what you are fetching with the view is associated with the group '**Boo**' then the view doesnt know it exists, so would never be able to show it but say there is no results for it.

What i would recommend is creating a taxonomy vocabulary with the terms: Foo, Bar, Boo.

In whatever content type your names belong to, create a term reference field, and link them to the terms.

In the view, fetch the taxonomy terms, create a relationship to the content type that references the taxonomy, and pull those through based on that. There is a setting in views for multiple results to combine into one field (so you would want to do that). Then you could add the 'Sorry no entries at this time!' as a field's **no results text**.

So to recap: VIEW => TAXONOMY TERMS => NAME CONTENT

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot get this to work. Is there an example of this somewhere I can see, because at the moment all I can do with taxonomy is replicate what I already have. What exactly do you mean by make a relationship to the content type in the view?